# Absolute positioning and blend groups in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In order to have absolute positioning of a tikzpicture (meaning, in terms of the "current page" node), we need to set the "overlay" option for the picture. It seems there is a conflict between this and setting blend groups within the picture. If this is so, is there a way to circumvent it? I'd like to have both functionalities working together in the same tikzpicture. As an MWE, take

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture,
    overlay,%<- Comment and uncomment to check the difference
    every path/.append style={fill opacity=0.75},
  ]
  \begin{scope}[blend group=lighten]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,blend group=darken]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,blend mode=multiply]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,blend group=screen]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm,blend group=overlay]
     \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
     \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
     \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Sorry but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @Alenanno:  It seems that with the `tikzpicture` `overlay` option and the `scope` `blend group` option, the `xshift` and `yshift` of the `scope` are being ignored. Must be a bug I think.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't available before, but I hope the question is clear now. I'd like to be able to use the `current page` node for absolute positioning, which requires setting the `overlay` option, but I also need to use blend groups inside the `tikzpicture`. If it is not yet clear, let me know and I'll post another MWE.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a known limitation rather than a bug as such. Or a known bug, if you like. At least, the TikZ manual mentions the problem, gives an explanation and directs you to a workaround. The following solution nests `tikzpicture` environments. I am aware this is generally a Bad Idea. However, I take it that it is the recommended workaround in this case as nesting is a feature of the manual's code.

From page 350:

> Note that when a transparency group is created, Tik Z must correctly
>   determine the size of the material inside the group. Usually, this is
>   no problem, but when you use things like overlay or transform canvas,
>   trouble may result. In this case, please consult Section 111 on how to
>   sidestep this problem in such cases.

Following the trail, on page 1097:

> Note that, depending on the driver, pgf may have to guess the size of
>   the contents of the transparency group (because such a group is put in
>   an XForm in pdf and a bounding box must be supplied). pgf will use
>   normally use the size of the picture’s bounding box at the end of the
>   transparency group plus a safety margin of 1cm. Under normal
>   circumstances, this will work nicely since the picture’s bounding box
>   contains everything anyway. However, if you have switched off the
>   picture size tracking or if you are using canvas transformations, you
>   may have to make sure that the bounding box is big enough. The trick
>   is to locally create a picture that is “large enough” and then insert
>   this picture into the main picture while ignoring the size.

Essentially, I think that TikZ cannot figure out the bounding box correctly since it needs to know this early on due to the use of a transparency group. At least for PDF, this appears to be the issue. The suggested workaround involves helping TikZ out by feeding it a suitable bounding box.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% see page 1097, following direction on page 350
  \node [overlay, remember picture, left] at (15,-5)
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.append style={fill opacity=0.75},
  ]
  \begin{scope}[blend group=lighten]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,blend group=darken]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,blend mode=multiply]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,blend group=screen]
    \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
    \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm,blend group=overlay]
     \fill[green] (90:1) circle[radius=1.5];
     \fill[orange] (180:1) circle[radius=1.5];
     \fill[red] (0:1) circle[radius=1.5];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: blend groups overlaid]